# I need using BeginInit with Guna.UI2.WinForms

Tags: c#, windows, memory

I need to put a BeginInit(); as an extension
with this code

```
this.UnsafeVolatileGetHandle.BeginInit();
```

and I'm using Guna.UI2 so I needed to declare a

```
private Guna2PictureBox UnsafeVolatileGetHandle;
```

But it returns the following error

```
"Guna2PictureBox" Does not contain a definition for "BeginInit" and it was not possible to find any "BeginInit" extension method that accepts a first argument of type "Guna2PictureBox"
```